# Not able to edit Spreadsheetgear workbookview component in visual studio 2019

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I have a old code which uses Spreadsheetgear 2012 for .net windows forms. I have to make changes in this workbookview worksheet but I am not able to edit it.
The orginal application was developed using visual studio 2008. Now, i am using visual studio 2019. Is this the reason I am not able to edit because of compatibility issues or am I missing something here?

I tried everything in the workbookview class but not able to find any solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.